# Gradle build failed while buliding a fragment in andriod application devolopment

Tags: java, xml

Iam getting an error as:"unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':couldnot resolve com.andriod.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
Please help.....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to ask questions.